# Simplify query in H2 database - alternative to TOP X PERCENT

Tags: sql, h2

I'm having performance issues with a query and was wondering how to simplify it.

I have a table "Evaluations" (Sample, Category, Jury, Value)
And created some custom functions to get some average values for each sample, so I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW Results AS 
SELECT  Sample, 
        Category,
        IFNULL(COUNT_VALID(Value),0) || ' / ' || COUNT(Value) AS Valid,
        CUSTOM_MEAN(Value) AS Mean,
        CUSTOM_MEDIAN(Value) AS Median
FROM Evaluations GROUP BY Sample, Category;
```

Then I want to have another field telling me if each sample is within the 30% of best valued samples of its category. It would be perfect to use TOP(X) PERCENT but it seems H2 doesn't support it so I made a second view that calculates the position in category multiplied by 100, divided by the total count in category and compared to 30:

```
CREATE VIEW Res AS 
SELECT  R1.*,

        CASE 
            WHEN ( 
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results R2 
                    WHERE R2.Category = R1.Category 
                    AND (R2.Mean > R1.Mean OR (R2.Mean = R1.Mean AND R2.Median > R1.Median))) + 1) * 100 
                / 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Results R2 WHERE R2.Category = R1.Category) ) 
                > 30
        THEN 'over 30%'
        ELSE 'within 30%'
        END as 30PERCENT

FROM Results R1 ORDER BY Mean DESC, Median DESC;
```

This works properly but with just 500 records it takes some time to retrieve the results. 
Could someone tell me a more efficient way of constructing this query?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I ended up creating a function that returns all this data as a table so it runs pretty faster than using aggregate functions and then the TOP X PERCENT alternative.